# BeautifulSoup: how to select certain tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am confused with how beautiful soup works, when you want to crab a child of a tag. 
So, I have the following HTML code

```
<div class="media item avatar profile">
<a href="http://..." class="media-link action-medialink">
<img class="media-item-img" src="http://...jpeg" alt="name" title="name" width="150" height="200">
</a>
</div>
```

I want to grab the src tag. I am using the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file_)
for x in soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'media item avatar profile'}).findNext('img'):
    print x
```

This prints the whole img tag. How do i select only the src ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would want something like:

```
soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'media item avatar profile'}).a.img['src']
```

---

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: html = """\
   ...: <div class="media item avatar profile">
   ...: <a href="http://..." class="media-link action-medialink">
   ...: <img class="media-item-img" src="http://...jpeg" alt="name" title="name" width="150" height="200">
   ...: </a>
   ...: </div>"""

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

In [4]: soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'media item avatar profile'}).a.img['src']
Out[4]: 'http://...jpeg'
```

Answer (score 6):

`src` is an [*attribute* of the tag](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes). Once you have the tag, access the attributes as you would dictionary keys; you only found the `a` tag so you need to navigate to the contained `img` tag too:

```
for x in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'media item avatar profile'}):
    print x.a.img['src']
```

Your code used `findNext()` which returns a *tag* object; looping over that gives you the children, so `x` was the `img` object. I changed this to be a bit more direct and clearer. `x` is now the `div`, and we navigate directly to the first `a` and contained `img` tag.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. I have tried it and a get the following error:
    print x['src']
    TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @evi: Updated; you have the `a` tag, not the `img` tag.

Comment: You don't have to loop as you are using `find` not `findAll`

Comment: I think you still have a loop too much :P `soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'media item avatar profile'})` return a `str`

Comment: @root: Ugh, I need more caffeine. My shell used `find_all('a')` still. :-P And the `find` returns an element (`<div>`), so looping will be over it's children, including any navigable string items.

Comment: **THIS WORKED LIKE A CHARM**

Answer (score 0):

`findNext` returns the first item that matches the given criteria and appears after the given tag in the document. Note that this means any tag it returns is not guaranteed to be a **child** of the given tag (e.g. a child of the `div` tag.)

Use `findChildren` to restrict to children of the given tag:

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs

file_ = '''<html>
<div class="media item avatar profile">
<a href="http://..." class="media-link action-medialink">
<img class="media-item-img" src="http://...jpeg" alt="name" title="name" width="150" height="200">
</a>
</div>  
</html>
'''
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(file_)
for x in soup.find(
        'div', attrs={'class':'media item avatar profile'}).findChildren('img'):
    print(x['src'])
```

yields

```
http://...jpeg
```